# Silent Uninstall lync 2013 client

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I would like to uninstall silently Lync 2013 client.
So far i tried two methods with no luck.

My first attempt is to use the recommended command for uninstall.
Using setup.exe manually i can uninstall Lync this way.

```
copy "%~DP0uninstall_lync.xml" "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup 

Controller\uninstall_lync.xml"

"%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall LYNCENTRY /dll OSETUP.DLL /config "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\uninstall_lync.xml"

Config File
<Configuration Product="LYNCENTRY">

<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="NEVER" />
<Logging Type="standard" Path="c:\windows\log\" Template="Microsoft Office Lync Uninstall(*).log" />

</Configuration>


I can uninstall Lync when i use this setup.exe manually

Log:
2014/11/24 14:49:11:039::[4844] PERF: TickCount=11665520 Name=OBootStrapper::Run Description=Begin function
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Operating System version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1. Platform ID: 2
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Running 32-bit setup on a 64-bit operating system.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe"  /uninstall LYNCENTRY /dll OSETUP.DLL /config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\uninstall_lync.xml"
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Parsing command line.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Config XML file specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\uninstall_lync.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Uninstall requested for product: LYNCENTRY
2014/11/24 14:49:11:040::[4844] Parsing config.xml at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\uninstall_lync.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Preferred product specified in config.xml to be: LYNCENTRY
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Parsed setting: SETUP_REBOOT with value: NEVER in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Logging type standard specified in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Log directory: c:\windows\log\ specified in config.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Log file template: Microsoft Office Lync Uninstall(*).log specified in config.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:060::[4844] Display level none specified in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:075::[4844] Using setup controller dll at location [C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUP.DLL].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:075::[4844] Verify file signature in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe"
2014/11/24 14:49:11:129::[4844] C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe is trusted.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:129::[4844] Verify file signature in "C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUP.DLL"
2014/11/24 14:49:11:198::[4844] C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUP.DLL is trusted.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:296::[4844] Using setup controller dll at [C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUP.DLL].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:296::[4844] PERF: TickCount=11665785 Name=OBootStrapper::Run Description=Calling RunSetup
2014/11/24 14:49:11:302::[4844] PERF: TickCount=11665785 Name=RunSetup Description=Begin function
2014/11/24 14:49:11:303::[4844] WER element [P2] is set to value [OSETUP.DLL]
2014/11/24 14:49:11:303::[4844] WER element [P3] is set to value [15.0.4569.1503]
2014/11/24 14:49:11:304::[4844] Catalyst execution began: 11/24/2014 14:49:11.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:305::[4844] Parsing config.xml at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\uninstall_lync.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Preferred product specified in config.xml to be: LYNCENTRY
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Parsed setting: SETUP_REBOOT with value: NEVER in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Logging type standard specified in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Log directory: c:\windows\log\ specified in config.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Log file template: Microsoft Office Lync Uninstall(*).log specified in config.xml
2014/11/24 14:49:11:307::[4844] Display level none specified in config.xml.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:308::[4844] Setupexe Resiliency Mode is set to [PerformIfApplicable]; thus Resiliency is [enabled] for the [UninstallExecutionMode]
2014/11/24 14:49:11:308::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller files for product [LYNCENTRY].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:308::[4844] Warning: Product registation information for 'LYNCENTRY' not detected. ErrorCode: 1011(0x3f3). Failed attempt to force-repair setupexe boot files.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:308::[4844] Searching for default versions of resource files under the folder [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:328::[4844] Found [1] resource files under the default folder.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:328::[4844] Running in [UninstallExecutionMode]. Run from TEMP folder at [C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:345::[4844] Loaded resource file [C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUPUI.DLL] (CultureTag=de-DE).
2014/11/24 14:49:11:345::[4844] WER element [SuppressModal] is set to value [false]
2014/11/24 14:49:11:346::[4844] WER element [P1] is set to value [15.0.4569.1503]
2014/11/24 14:49:11:346::[4844] Loaded Dll : C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000214\OSETUP.DLL.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:346::[4844] Catalyst version is : 15.0.4569.1503
2014/11/24 14:49:11:346::[4844] JobExecutionMode is UninstallExecutionMode.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:547::[4844] Opening registry key: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNCENTRY.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:547::[4844] Opening registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNCENTRY.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:548::[4844] IsProductTransitionToMModeSafe: An exception was caught, therefore transition to MMode is unsafe for product:
2014/11/24 14:49:11:548::[4844] Error: Product is not installed, therefore transition to MMode is unsafe for product: LYNCENTRY Type: 27::InstalledProductStateCorrupt.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:548::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller files for all Products.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:548::[4844] Opening registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller files for product [LYNC].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Opening registry key: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNC.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Opening registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNC.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-002A-0407-1000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-002A-0407-1000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:11:549::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:13:038::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-002A-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:13:038::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-002A-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:13:038::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:15:639::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:15:639::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:15:639::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:18:424::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-001F-0410-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:18:424::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-001F-0410-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:18:424::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:20:222::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-001F-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:20:222::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-001F-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:20:222::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:21:766::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-001F-040C-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:21:767::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-001F-040C-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:21:767::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:23:339::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-001F-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:23:339::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-001F-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:23:340::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:25:046::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-002C-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:25:047::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-002C-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:25:048::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:26:619::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-012B-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:26:620::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-012B-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:26:620::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:28:951::[4844] Ensuring the install-state of setup controller feature[SetupControllerFiles] for product[{90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}].
2014/11/24 14:49:28:951::[4844] Product INSTALLSTATE for ProductCode '{90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}' is '5'.
2014/11/24 14:49:28:952::[4844] Feature INSTALLSTATE for Feature 'SetupXmlFiles' is '3'.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] Opening registry key: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNCENTRY.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] Opening registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office15.LYNCENTRY.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] IsProductTransitionToMModeSafe: An exception was caught, therefore transition to MMode is unsafe for product:
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] Error: Product is not installed, therefore transition to MMode is unsafe for product: LYNCENTRY Type: 27::InstalledProductStateCorrupt.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] Not showing message because suppress modal has been set.  Title: 'Setupfehler', Message: 'Diese Produktinstallation wurde besch..digt. F..hren Sie Setup erneut von der CD, DVD oder einer anderen urspr..nglichen Installationsquelle aus.'
2014/11/24 14:49:36:136::[4844] Message returned: 1
2014/11/24 14:49:36:141::[4844] Error: Catalyst boot time check failed Type: 66::PreReqCheckFailure.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:141::[4844] Catalyst execution finished: 11/24/2014 14:49:36.  Return code: 30066.  Exception caught: PreReqCheckFailure.
2014/11/24 14:49:36:141::[4844] PERF: TickCount=11690621 Name=RunSetup Description=End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are different Product ID's.
I looked up setup.xml under lync.ww and my Setup ID was only "Lync"

Answer (score 0):

My second attempt is to see which new msi flies are created while installing Lync a lookup Up the ProductCode ( it's the same one which is added to registry)

MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} /qn /norestart /L*v "c:\windows\log\Microsoft_Lync_2013_Update_KB2817626_x86_0185_Install.LOG"

When i use this msi manually it runs through without any error but won't uninstall Lync.
Log

```
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:612]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:628]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:631]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:631]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:631]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:645]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:645]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:645]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:645]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}'.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:645]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:649]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\bfb3d2.msp'.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:650]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\bfb37a.msp'.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:650]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\bfb386.msp'.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:651]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}, Product version: 15.0.4569.1506, Upgrade code: {00150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}, Product language 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchMetadata
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: {27D7A8D0-8E28-4A2A-A1D4-473E31DF6438} -
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: {73E81413-5A7E-40A3-9BD5-821ADDF30B10} -
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: {D448DFE1-B83E-4394-9484-25563EFBF58D} -
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:652]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:653]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:653]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0401000015.0.4569.1506
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0401000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0401-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:653]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0401000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:653]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0401000015.0.4420.1017
1: 2746 2: 90006E0401000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0401-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0401000015.0.4420.1017 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0401-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:654]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0401000015.0.4420.1017.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:654]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0402000015.0.4481.1005
1: 2746 2: 90006E0401000015.0.4420.1017 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0401-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0402000015.0.4481.1005 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:654]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0402000015.0.4481.1005.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:654]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0402000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0402000015.0.4481.1005 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0402000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0402000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0402000015.0.4505.1008
1: 2746 2: 90006E0402000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0402000015.0.4505.1008 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0402000015.0.4505.1008.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0402000015.0.4454.1509
1: 2746 2: 90006E0402000015.0.4505.1008 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0402000015.0.4454.1509 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0402000015.0.4454.1509.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:655]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0405000015.0.4481.1005
1: 2746 2: 90006E0402000015.0.4454.1509 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0402-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0405000015.0.4481.1005 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0405000015.0.4481.1005.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0405000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0405000015.0.4481.1005 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0405000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0405000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0405000015.0.4505.1008
1: 2746 2: 90006E0405000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0405000015.0.4505.1008 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0405000015.0.4505.1008.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:656]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0405000015.0.4454.1004
1: 2746 2: 90006E0405000015.0.4505.1008 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0405000015.0.4454.1004 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0405000015.0.4454.1004.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0406000015.0.4481.1005
1: 2746 2: 90006E0405000015.0.4454.1004 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0405-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0406000015.0.4481.1005 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0406000015.0.4481.1005.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0406000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0406000015.0.4481.1005 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0406000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0406000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:657]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0406000015.0.4433.1507
1: 2746 2: 90006E0406000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0406000015.0.4433.1507 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0406000015.0.4433.1507.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0406000015.0.4505.1008
1: 2746 2: 90006E0406000015.0.4433.1507 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0406000015.0.4505.1008 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0406000015.0.4505.1008.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0407000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0406000015.0.4505.1008 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0406-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0407000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0407000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:658]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0407000015.0.4420.1017
1: 2746 2: 90006E0407000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0407000015.0.4420.1017 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:659]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0407000015.0.4420.1017.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:659]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0408000015.0.4481.1005
1: 2746 2: 90006E0407000015.0.4420.1017 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0407-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0408000015.0.4481.1005 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:659]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0408000015.0.4481.1005.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:659]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0408000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0408000015.0.4481.1005 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0408000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0408000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0408000015.0.4505.1008
1: 2746 2: 90006E0408000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0408000015.0.4505.1008 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0408000015.0.4505.1008.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0408000015.0.4454.1004
1: 2746 2: 90006E0408000015.0.4505.1008 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0408000015.0.4454.1004 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0408000015.0.4454.1004.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:660]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0409000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0408000015.0.4454.1004 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0408-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0409000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:661]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0409000015.0.4569.1506.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:661]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0409000015.0.4420.1017
1: 2746 2: 90006E0409000015.0.4569.1506 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0409000015.0.4420.1017 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:661]: Skipping validation for patch transform #90006E0409000015.0.4420.1017.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:10:52:661]: Looking for patch transform: 90006E0C0A000015.0.4569.1506
1: 2746 2: 90006E0409000015.0.4420.1017 3: C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi 4: {90150000-006E-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} 5: {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform 90006E0C0A000015.0.4569.1506 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\bfb379.msi. Expected product {90150000-006E-0C0A-0000-0000000FF1CE}, found product {90150000-012C-0000-0000-0000000

MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:072]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:073]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:074]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:074]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:074]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:074]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:076]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:076]: Transforming table Error.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:076]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:076]: Produkt: Microsoft Lync 2013 -- Das Entfernen ist fehlgeschlagen.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:077]: Das Produkt wurde durch Windows Installer entfernt. Produktname: Microsoft Lync 2013. Produktversion: 15.0.4569.1506. Produktsprache: 0. Hersteller: Microsoft Corporation. Erfolg- bzw. Fehlerstatus der Deinstallation: 1603.
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:079]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\bfb5a2.mst
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:085]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:085]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\bfb5a2.mst
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:085]: Unable to delete the file outside of the engine. LastError = 2
MSI (s) (10:20) [15:16:59:085]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:16:59:089]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:16:59:089]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Protokollierung beendet: 24.11.2014  15:16:59 ===
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:16:59:090]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:16:59:090]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (10:4C) [15:16:59:090]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
```